# AngularJS: Initialise local variable in directive controller from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Imagine a typical scenario where you have a parent controller and a directive with its own controller. From the parent controller, I am passing a one-way binding method that acts as a getter for some object (using &) and I need to initialise a variable in the directive locally. First it will be initialised with what's in the parent (i.e. calls the getter), then it will be modified locally in the directive, and finally on destroy return it back to the parent. Here's is a snippet.

```
app.directive('myDirective', [..., function(...) {
    return {
        scope: {
           getObject: '&object',
           onDestroy: '&'
        },
        templateURL: .....,
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            // The problem is that when I do this, innerObject is {}.
            // $scope.getObject() does return something correctly, not 
            // a question of bad binding, but because in the lifecycle 
            // it initialises innerObject before binding $scope.getObject()
            var innerObject = deep_copy($scope.getObject());

            $scope.someFunction = function() {
                // alters innerObject, but not the parent Object
            }

            ... // on destroying the directive
                onDestroy(innerObject)
                // this basically updates the object in the parent controller

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that `innerObject` gets initialised too quickly, before `$scope.getObject` binds to the actual object value, thus it initialises as `{}` and not the object in the parent. If this were React, I'd have initialised it in a constructor with a prop.

What am I missing here?

Before anyone mentions it:

- No, I don't want to use two way binding. I only want to update the parent controller when the directive finishes a certain flow.
- I have a very good reason to be using `controller` and not `link`
- I'm aware of `let` and `const`, but this is an old project
- I'd rather avoid events

Comment: What's the code for the parent controller where `getObject()` is defined?

Comment: `getObject()` binds to `$scope.object` in the parent controller. It's not something I implement, it's just the nature of how I used `&object`, but calling `getObject()` simply returns `$parent.$scope.object`. I know it works through debugging, or simply using it in other local directive scope functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways can get data inside the parent controller  :

> The first way :

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
      angular.module('yourApp',[])
        .controller('parent',parentOptions)
        .controller('child',childOptions)
        
          function parentOptions($scope){
              function 
            console.log('hello parent');
          }
          
           function childOptions($scope){
            console.log('hello child');
          }
      

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<section data-ng-app="yourApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="parent">
     <div data-ng-controller="child">
     
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

> Second way

can use $controller and call parent controller inside child controller

> Third way

cat set getObject() inside $rootSope and call  $rootScope.getObject();